# Java do loop repeat until valid entry

Tags: java, do-while

I'm creating a  Java project using a do-while loop to get a number from the user between 5 and 15. After this, I will create a square and triangle using the number the user entered.

I'm currently stuck on making my question repeat. After I run the program it runs fine until I input a number the second time the user is prompted to enter a number. It won't print if the number is invalid or not.

I tried moving the second **"Enter a number..."** inside of the do-loop but that just printed with the **"Sorry, invalid"** prompt. I did something similar with a case statement inside a while loop and it ran fine but I'm having difficulty with the do loop.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class doLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;
    int minimum = 5;
    int maximum = 15;

    System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + ":" );



        do {
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number >= minimum && number <= 15) 
                break;
            else 
                System.out.print("Sorry, invalid");
            break;
        } while (false); 
        System.out.print("\nEnter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + ":" );
        number =  input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: `break;`, `break;`, `while (false);`? Think about the control-flow again.

Comment: @tkausl totally agree. It seems she comes from another language and she should read something about Java programming

Comment: The do-while semantics are not the same as repeat-until semantics ... `repeat ... until(false)` is equivalent to `do ... while(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, use `break` inside a while loop is considered a bad practice. You should have something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;
    int minimum = 5;
    int maximum = 15;

    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a number between" + " " + minimum + " " + "and" + " " + maximum + ":" );
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (number < minimum || number > maximum) 
            System.out.print("Sorry, invalid");
    } while (number < minimum || number > maximum); 

}
```

Comment: wow! thank you that helped a lot! why is it considered bad practice to use break inside a while loop? Is that still the case if its in an if-statement or case-statement?

Comment: Using `break` breaks (yes, this is redundant) the execution flow and, in most cases, makes code difficult to understand. There are some cases when is mostly accepted to use because it makes just the opposite, it helps to follow the flow of the code easily, but even then, and specially if you're learning programming, you should avoid using it.

Comment: can i add another loop into the do loop for the second part of the program. whenever i research nested loops, I only see examples with for loops. If I can't use a nested loop to add the patterns. Would I be able to add another loop and use the user's input to create the pattern? Sorry for all of the questions. This is my first time using loops.

Comment: Sure, you can use anything inside a loop (except `break`s XD)

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code in the placement of your break and scanner input. If you really want to stay true to what you have, I find it much simpler to just add a boolean check instead of using a break. Below you can see I also put final so that way you know, and is a best practice that, that variable should not be altered or tampered with in code. I added a boolean since you wanted to check the do while for false, then we set it to true if it passes the if statement you made.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int number;
boolean check = false;

// Final, because they are constant through-out the program
final int minimum = 5;
final int maximum = 15;

do {
    System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + ":" );
    number = input.nextInt();
    if (number >= minimum && number <= maximum) 
        check = true;
    else 
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid");
    break;
} while (check); 


}
```